# Bundle fails on the Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to run the Rails application on the server. But it does not seem to be running and throws up the following error

```
Using jquery-rails 3.1.2

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150202-30975-1vno3hv.rb extconf.rb 
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.17 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/mysql2-0.3.17/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.17), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17'` succeeds before bundling.
```

**When i try to install mysql2 i am getting the following error.**

```
root@99atoms-staging:/var/www/noise# gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150202-631-fm19nq.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.17 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/mysql2-0.3.17/gem_make.out
```

Comment: is mysql installed ?

Comment: @Nithin yes i have installed it. n checked. i am still geting the same error. i tried before installing then installed and tried it

Comment: Which machine you are using? OSX or Ubuntu or Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned Ubuntu,you need to install development package first.

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

and then do

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17'
```

Comment: Can you please tell why did the bundle fail?

Comment: I don't know,but i guess some gems need the specific packages to run in a machine.So the bundler failed because there is no package installed in your machine for mysql2 gem to run.